# jQuery UI draggable/droppable not working in Firefox 3.6.13

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, firefox3.6

I'm using .draggable and .droppable in a project and they work fine in Chrome and IE, but in Firefox 3.6.13 (Windows... I haven't tested this with FF on linux), they don't. I was about to post my code but I decided I'd try the draggable/droppable demos on the jQuery UI website before subjecting anyone to that :-)

Sure enough, the following demos do not work (for me at least) in Firefox 3.6.13:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/

http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/

Can anyone reproduce this? Does anyone know why and/or if there's a solution to this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Both demos work in Firefox 3.6.13 (on Ubuntu).

Comment: Both demos work in Firefox 3.6.13 on Windows 7 32 bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I've figured it out! It has to do with this bug in jQuery 1.5.0:

http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/6955

Thanks to all of you!

Answer (score 1):

Both run fine on 3.6.10 and 3.6.13 for me (On vanilla firefox without plugins, win7 64bit)

Comment: Weird. Thanks for trying! I'd also like to add that I'm testing this on windows server 2003 standard.

Answer (score 1):

don't work for me too with FF 3.13.
The object is table, I'm working on MS Windows 7 x64.
It work fine on IE8, Chrome, Opera and Safari

Creating a second draggable element and the first one become draggable...

Answer (score 1):

works fine for me in 3.6.13

Have you tried looking at the console in FireBug to see if there are any errors being kicked up?